# Maximum time period

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset that lists ID's (EmployeeID), the time period in quarters and years, four digit code, last two numbers of year are first 2 numbers, quarter number is second two.  Quarter 1 of 2013 would be '1301' (Quarter)  It includes active and previous employees.  It also has sales (Sales).  The dataset has one row per ID, per quarter.   I need sales at the  most recent quarter.

here is my code:

```
select EmployeeID, max(Quarter), Sales
from dataset;
```

Clearly this is wrong because it wants me to group by employeeid and sales etc and it gives me multiple rows for each employeeid.

See above.

I need output of 1 row  per EmployeeID giving me their most recent quarter and sales during that quarter.

Comment: Share sample input and desired output data

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: oracle sql, sorry.

Comment: @dbwhite64 Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: FYI, more commonly, quarters are represented with a 4-digit year, a `Q`, and a one-digit number. Some might put a hyphen between year and `Q`. Ex: `2019Q1` or `2019-Q1`. Though not defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), the latter style follows the conventions of that standard.

Comment: Thanks; but i am not the DBA. haha.  Ill keep notes on how to edit vs comment though.  Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All sales from the last quarter:**

```
select *
from dataset
where quarter = (select max(quarter) from dataset);
```

**All sales an employee did last (i.e. last quarter per employee = different last quarters):**

```
select *
from dataset
where (employeeid, quarter) in
(
  select employeeid, max(quarter)
  from dataset
  group by employeeid
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using window functions, you can create a derived table with one record for each employee and the max quarter, then inner join that back on the datset.

```
;WITH MaxQuarter AS(select EmployeeID, MaxQuarter = max(Quarter) from dataset)

select EmployeeID, Quarter, Sales 
from dataset ds
inner join MaxQuarter m on m.EmployeeID = ds.EmployeeID and m.MaxQuarter = ds.Quarter
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using SQL Server you can use a common table expression

```
WITH MaxQuarters(EmployeeID, MaxQuarter)  
AS   
(  
    SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(Quarter) as MaxQuarter  
    FROM dataset  
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
)  
SELECT EmployeeID, Quarter, Sales  
FROM dataset ds
JOIN MaxQuarters mq on ds.EmployeeID = mq.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent quarter overall:

```
select ds.*
from dataset ds
where ds.quarter = (select max(ds2.quarter) from dataset ds2);
```

If you want the maximum *per employee*:

```
select ds.*
from dataset ds
where ds.quarter = (select max(ds2.quarter)
                    from dataset ds2
                    where ds2.employeeid = ds.employeeid
                   );
```

Or, in Oracle, you can use `keep` and aggregation:

```
select employeeid, max(quarter),
       max(sales) keep (dense_rank first order by quarter desc) as sales
from dataset
group by employeeid
```

Comment: I appreciate the time.  The oracle version gave me a "missing right parenthesis" error after "dec)" in line 2.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @dbwhite64: That's a typo. Make it `desc` for "descending". (You could also remove it completely for ascending order and change `first` to `last` instead .)